# Ensure all data is flushed from user space to eMMC memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, synchronization, embedded, driver

I am working with embedded Linux system, where software should be replaced in power fail safe manner, and that when we signal that procedure is complete power failure should not negatively affect the system.

Documentation for sync syscall mentions that this flushes only the kernel buffers, and internal device (like eMMC) buffers can still be not fully flushed.

I was looking through /dev/mmc directories, and found the file called "removeable" which should allow to have behavior similar to actually removable devices (where power is disconected on removal in abrupt way).

Does Linux eMMC drivers has sth more dedicated to fully flush eMMC card/prepare it for power loss?

Comment: You can't fix power failure. It's out of software issue. The way you can minimize it is to switch to sync mode (100x times worse performance), check for FUA bit.

Comment: I do not need to have such unit access for the whole process, but ability to get checkpoint (like those changes were committed, its safe mark data as valid, confirm over network that process was succesfull or to turn off the power)